# SQL Server BackEnd Access Front-End ODBC Error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I can read/write/update the table fine in SSMS, I can open/read/write the table fine if I open the table itself in Access 2013, but if I try to query the table, I get the generic access error message of

> ODBC -- call failed

This table has 558,672 rows in it.  I have tried using a DSNLess connection with VBA as well as a manually linking the table in through the toolbar in access.  What is causing access to throw this error?

**EDIT**
I have also tried to compact and repair the database to no avail.

**EDIT #2**
It seems that only one element (a subform) is throwing the ODBC error.  The peculiar thing is the main form is based on the same datasource that the sub form is, but only the subform is throwing an error?

Comment: By 'query the table' do you mean create a select query in access and run it?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - yes that is what I meant with query the table, sorry I was not clear.

Comment: You should probably post your query. Is the query against a linked table or is it a pass through query?

Comment: Against a linked table.  It is a straight Select query.  If I select 1 field or 10 it throws the same error.  I have even tried to create a view of just 2 - 3 fields to see if maybe a field was corrupted but same result.

Comment: how about 'select 1 from table'

Comment: Let's see - version of SQL Server? O/S version, and has it been updated recently. Do we have 32 bit ODBC drivers on a 64 bit SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2 - Win 10 64X, Access 2013 64X and 64bit ODBC driver.  I am able to succesfully link in other tables in this database as well as other databases, just this 1 table is giving me grief.

Comment: Can you post to us the table definition

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before here are the thing I had to change to access table with MS Access and edit it.

1.your tables should have a primary key. In the column properties, set identity specification to yes, and Identity increment by 1. I would prefer to set a completely new column with int data type.
2. No null values in boolean fields everything should be  1 or 0.  and set a constraint to 0.

Comment: I have a PK set to identity and increment by 1, all the other fields are either datetime, nvarchar(255) or real.

Comment: Re-Link the table. When linking it, it will ask you for a unique identifier for each table. If you do not select one then you will have issues as it will not know which record to update when you make changes to your data and can result it updating multiple records instead of the one single one you wanted to update.

In the event you have already done this then I guess it must be something else but it certainly sounds like the issue the above person posted.